# aspnet-core-ad-authentication project HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I run [this](https://github.com/chsword/aspnet-core-ad-authentication) project
in Visual Studio 2019 it loads page with the following error message

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure Common causes of this issue:
>
> ```
> The application process failed to start
> The application process started but then stopped
> The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
> ```
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> ```
> Check the system event log for error messages
> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
> ```
>
> For more information visit:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

How to fix it?

Comment: Hey ,make sure that you have the same version of sdk asp.net core as your visual studio 2019 have.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 comes with .NET Core 2.2 bits, so running a .NET Core 1.1 project can trigger incompatibility (.NET Core 1.1 runtime is missing). Either you install the right runtime, or you upgrade the project to 2.1 or 2.2.

Comment: @LexLi Do you know, how to upgrade the project to .NET Core 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet the same problem when I run with IIS Express.When I run with command line it tells me that I do not have 1.1 SDK.

You need to install the [.net core 1.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/1.1) before run the appliaction.

Answer (score 1):

to complete Ryan answer, you have to install the same version of sdk asp.net core as your project includes. for me it was 2.1 so I installed 2.1 sdk.